# Equal matrix coefficients - unitary representations

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $G$ be a locally compact group and let $\pi$ and $\rho$ be irreducible unitary representations of $G$. Let $u,v \in \mathcal{H}_\pi$ and $x,y \in \mathcal{H}_\rho$ be non-zero vectors which satisfy $\Vert u \Vert = \Vert x \Vert$ and $\Vert v \Vert = \Vert y \Vert$, and $\varphi_{u,v}^\pi = \varphi_{x,y}^\rho$ (that is, the matrix coefficients are equal).

I'd like to show that the two representations $\pi$ and $\rho$ are isomorphic, and, secondly, that there exists a unitary isomorphism $U: \mathcal{H}_\pi \rightarrow \mathcal{H}_\rho$ between $\pi$ and $\rho$ with $U(u) = x$ and $U(v) = y$.

What I know is the following:

1. Since the representations are irreducible they are cyclic and any non-zero vector will be a generator.
2. If there exists $w \in \mathcal{H}_\pi$ and $z \in \mathcal{H}_\rho$ such that the diagonal matrix coefficients $\varphi_{w}^\pi = \varphi_{z}^\rho$ are equal, then $\pi$ restricted to the cyclic subspace $\langle w \rangle_\pi$ is unitarily isomorphic to $\rho$ restricted to the cyclic subspace $\langle z \rangle_\rho$ via a unitary isomorphism that sends $w$ to $z$.
3. The map $\mathcal{H}_\pi \ni u \mapsto \varphi_{u,v}^\pi \in C(G)$ is linear and injective.
4. One has $\varphi_{\pi_gu,v}^\pi(h) = \varphi_{u,v}^\pi(hg)$ and $\varphi_{u,\pi_gv}^\pi(h) = \varphi_{u,v}^\pi(g^{-1}h)$.

I'd be happy about any hint/insight on how I can continue from here.
Thank you.